# Farewell my Diamond

Tags: discussion

[image: Farewell my little blue diamond]

As the SFSE has fully (almost) graduated, and the [elections are underway](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election) and as I am not planning to nominate myself for moderation,  I'd like to thank everyone here at SFSE. On the first day I saw this site (thank you Laceysnr) I've known it's going to be a great place for information and learning (and some Q&A).

As avid user on the first days, I was happy to assist, volunteer and do anything I could to make this site flourish.

As life is more demanding, and takes precedence on my virtual heroes (except WoW and Diablo3 maybe), I was happy to see that many other users have become active in handling/cleaning/voting and making the site a living entity, and for the past months (maybe 8 or 10) I have stepped down, and seen others take the active part.

I am happy to see where it is today, and I am happy to know that I was one of those who brought it to this point.

I know I will not have the time, nor the drive to keep on administrating the site, so just for safe keeping, here's the last days of my diamond days on SFSE :-)

- I just hope I will get an admin Tshirt if/when they come available  :-P

I'll still be around, poking, harassing, and nudging you all, don't worry...

Comment: Thanks for all your help, the site couldn't have gotten this far without you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Saariko, I wasn't here when this site initially opened but have immensely benefited from the efforts of those like you who "paved the way" and laid the foundation for what's here today. You've helped create something that will live on long beyond your tenure here in the moderator's chair. I think you can be very proud of what you've helped bring to fruition.

Thank you for having the foresight to recognize a good idea, commit yourself to it and have the faith to build it. In choosing to build it, many like me have come to your *"Field of Dreams"*.

in my opinion, that T-shirt has been well earned . ;)

Comment: Thank you, I have 4 kids and SFSE as my legacy ;-)

Comment: @Saariko 4 kids successful admin and still time for gaming.  I like it!

Comment: Yea, as I return from a sport injury, need to get back practicing to my next Triathlon.

Comment: @Saariko can relate to that. Used to race bicycles myself and often trained with several triathletes. Takes a lot of time and energy. Good luck with the return to training. Can be a challenge to come back from an injury at times. Been there and done that after having been in serious crashes during races.